# How do I connect to MS SQL Server instance?

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I hope you can help with something that's a bit puzzling.

I'm trying to modify a PHP application written by someone else. It accesses an MS SQL Server 2008 database and returns some stuff. The applications works fine in the live environment, but when I copy it onto my local machine (which I've set up to mirror the live environment), the connection fails with:

> This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client.
>   Access the following URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012
>   Native Client ODBC driver for x86:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

I've checked my local PHP installation and the drivers are already installed, the php.ini is pointing to the correct drivers and the drivers should be valid for my version of php (5.3.9).

Can anyone suggest what else I need to check for? Obviously, as the file is a straight copy, any connections strings / logins / server names will be identical, but only the live version sitting on the hosting server is working.

Comment: Well, do you have the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client installed? That's not the driver itself, it's used by the driver.

Comment: @Ambulance - Please note that you can answer your own question (this site actually encourages it). A question that contains its own answer cannot be tagged as answered and breaks the Q&A format.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found the answer. My local machine had SQL Server Native Client 2008 **R2** installed. Apparently, I needed the older version. Installed the SQL Server Native Client 2008 not-R2 version and it's now working.

Comment: As the error message suggests, SQL Server Nativeclient **2012** is also a valid client even for older DB versions. I've personally used it with SQLSRV 3 to connect to SQL Server 2005 databases.